# What's the error and how to solve this in PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I tried to make a form on my Website with MySQL and PHP but it doesn't save anything in the Database, but the view from the Website isn't like there is an error. What's the error and how to solve it, so I hope, you can solve this.
I think the error is in execute but I'm not sure a and I couldn't solve it.

```
$dcuser = $_POST["user"];
$tmpuser = $_POST["tmpuser"];
$spedi = $_POST["spedi"];
$selecte = $_POST["selecte"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
$save = $_POST["save"];

$test2 = [$dcuser, $tmpuser, $spedi, $selecte, $data, $save];

if (!isset($dcuser)) {
   echo("test");
}
else{
   if (!isset($tmpuser)) {
       echo("test");
   }
   else {
       if (!isset($spedi)) {
           echo("test");
       }
       else {
           if (!isset($selecte)) {
               echo("test");
           }
           else {
               if (!isset($data)) {
                   echo("test");
               }
               else {
                   if (!isset($save)) {
                       echo("test");
                   }
                   else {
                       echo($test2->a);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'user';
$DATABASE_PASS = 'pw';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'form';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

$test[] = $_POST['user'];
$test[] = $_POST['tmpuser'];
$test[] = $_POST['spedi'];
$test[] = $_POST['selecte'];
$test[] = $_POST['data'];
$test[] = $_POST['save'];

$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO konvoi (user, tmpuser, spedi, selecte, daten, save) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($test[0], $test[1], $test[2], $test[3], $test[4], $test[5]));

if(isset($dcuser)) {
 if(isset($tmpuser)) {
   if(isset($spedi)) {
     if(isset($selecte)) {
       if(isset($data)) {
         if(isset($save)) {
           echo '<p>User: '.$test[0].'</p>';
           echo '<p>TMP: '.$test[1].'</p>';
           echo '<p>Spedi: '.$test[2].'</p>';
           echo '<p>selecte: '.$test[3].'</p>';
           echo '<p>Data: '.$test[4].'</p>';
           echo '<p>Save: '.$test[5].'</p>';
         }  else {
           echo 'test6';
         }
       }  else {
         echo 'test5';
       }
     }  else {
       echo 'test4';
     }
   }  else {
     echo 'test3';
   }
 }  else {
   echo 'test2';
 }
} else {
 echo 'test1';
}
```

HTML:

````
  <form action="convoi.php" method="post">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Discord Username" name="user" required>
        <br>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="TMP Username" name="tmpuser" required>
        <br>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Spedition" name="spedi" required>
        <br>
        <label class="frage">Wie hast du von dem Konvoi erfahren?:
          <br>
          <select name = "selecte" class="option" required>
                <option>Eigene Spedition</option>
                <option>Anderer Spedition</option>
                <option>Unsere Internetseite</option>
                <option>Werbung von einem Spieler</option>
            <option>Sonstiges</option>
            <option>Keine Angabe</option>
            </select>
        </label>
          <br>
        <p class="datenschutz"><input type="checkbox" name="data" required>Ich aktzeptiere die <a class="data" href="https://otendex.de/datenschutz/#">Datenschutzbestimmungen </a></p>
        <p class="datenschutz"><input type="checkbox" name="save" required> Ich stimme zu das meine Daten gespeichert werden</p>
        </input>
        <div class="h-captcha" style="text-align: center"data-sitekey="22995024-4ceb-4169-a763-d81020ed4eea"></div>
        <button class="button" type="submit" value="Absenden">
          Absenden
        </button>
      </form>```
````

Comment: `$statement->execute(array($test[0], $test[1], $test[2], $test[3], $test[4], $test[5]))` <-- save yourself time and type instead : `$statement->execute($test);`

Comment: Looks here the problem `echo($test2->a);`

Comment: same problem after your solutions

Comment: What is your form code? Depending upon what that is - the testing of isset() on every input should be replaced with empty() instea. Look up the difference between the two. And you "Validation" is structure should be different instead of using a nested IF, test each one separately with it's own error message.

Comment: $selecte what is it???

Comment: $selecte not set

Comment: $pommes change to $selecte

Comment: @A.Sang sry had fixed this and forgot to edit the post here

Comment: Now working or not?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw if you mean html with form code, i've added it to the Question.

Comment: @A.Sang Is not working

Comment: <select name = "pommes"  change this

Comment: please check all var are correct.

Comment: and remove this echo($test2->a);

Comment: i tested your code and working remove this echo($test2->a); and change <select name = "selecte"

Comment: Avoid the [arrow anti-pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern)!

Comment: Okay I try tomorrow, because im now in bed.

Comment: You are mixing PDO and mysqli!

Comment: Yes, now I know this, but **what** I have to change?

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried using

```
   echo $statement->execute
```

after $statement->execute. If it's db error it will print that on screen?

Comment: It prints nothing